# How Laravel loads relations?

Tags: laravel

Let's say we do this
`$users = User::with('comments')->get();` 
it will execute

```
select * from `users`
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I don't understand how Laravel knows which comments are linked to which user? Does Laravel do some extra code after it executes queries to link each user to his comments so when we do:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->comments //Laravel knows that which comments to load for this user
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how Laravel knows which comments are linked to which user

Well, in your example every comment has a `user_id` field, it is not hard to loop over the comments and assign every one to the correct user.

> Does Laravel do some extra code after it executes queries to link each user to his comments

Definitely. You should take a deep dive on laravel internals (https://github.com/laravel/framework/) to find the exact parsing code though.

I guess that logically it does something along the lines of:

- Perform the base query (`select * from users`), creates a collection of `User` for each row returned
- Get the unique user IDS in the collection
- Perform the relationship query (`select * from comments where comments.user_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`), creates a collection of `Comment`, loop over the collection and assign every comment to the proper User
- Return the collection of Users

Answer (score 1):

lets examine a simpler example first.

```
$user = User::with('comments')->find(1); // user with id 1
```

now laravel knows which comments belong to user just because of the id :

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1    // gets user
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id` = 1 // gets user's comments
```

now when you need comments for more then one user, this happens:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id` in (/* user ids */)
```

and then appends each comment to their relative user's collection

Answer (score 1):

To build database queries using Eloquent under the hood, Laravel uses [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php) instance.

When you call `with` method, you add a relation to `eagetLoad` array property of the builder:

```php
public function with($relations, $callback = null)
{
    if ($callback instanceof Closure) {
        $eagerLoad = $this->parseWithRelations([$relations => $callback]);
    } else {
        $eagerLoad = $this->parseWithRelations(is_string($relations) ? func_get_args() : $relations);
    }

    $this->eagerLoad = array_merge($this->eagerLoad, $eagerLoad);

    return $this;
}
```

Then when you try to receive a result using `get`, `find`, `findOrFail`, etc., builder calls `eagerLoadRelation` method:

```php
protected function eagerLoadRelation(array $models, $name, Closure $constraints)
{
    // First we will "back up" the existing where conditions on the query so we can
    // add our eager constraints. Then we will merge the wheres that were on the
    // query back to it in order that any where conditions might be specified.
    $relation = $this->getRelation($name);

    $relation->addEagerConstraints($models);

    $constraints($relation);

    // Once we have the results, we just match those back up to their parent models
    // using the relationship instance. Then we just return the finished arrays
    // of models which have been eagerly hydrated and are readied for return.
    return $relation->match(
        $relation->initRelation($models, $name),
        $relation->getEager(), $name
    );
}
```

The matching with parent models is happening within `match` method, which implemented differently for every relation type (you may see [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/tree/master/Eloquent/Relations) namespace). For most relations the `matchOneOrMany` method is used (dictionary is a simple collection, that filtered by foreign key for relation):

```php
    protected function matchOneOrMany(array $models, Collection $results, $relation, $type)
    {
        $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);

        // Once we have the dictionary we can simply spin through the parent models to
        // link them up with their children using the keyed dictionary to make the
        // matching very convenient and easy work. Then we'll just return them.
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            if (isset($dictionary[$key = $this->getDictionaryKey($model->getAttribute($this->localKey))])) {
                $model->setRelation(
                    $relation, $this->getRelationValue($dictionary, $key, $type)
                );
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try using the die and dump function for "debugging" and understanding the structure of your queries whenever you're confused about the structures, then things will start making more sense.

```
dd($users)
```

You'll find that Laravel will neatly fetch the comments of each user if everything is set up correctly in your models.

Comment: So it does extra logic after queries are executed in order to link each user to his comments